# PHP Pagination for MySQL database - display the first page by default

Tags: php, mysql

Code:

```
$totalItemsRequired = 8;
$query = "SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY origin ASC ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ($result == false)
    {
    echo "<p>Selecting all fruits failed.</p>";
    }
  else
    {
    $totalRecords = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $totalPages = ceil($totalRecords / $totalItemsRequired);
    echo "<p>Page: ";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++)
        {
        echo "<a href='?page=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a> ";
        }

    echo "</p>";
    if (isset($_GET['page']))
        {
        $currentPageNum = $_GET['page'];
        $offset = ($currentPageNum - 1) * $totalItemsRequired;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM fruits " . "LIMIT " . $offset . ", " . $totalItemsRequired;
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if ($result == false)
            {
            echo "<p>Selecting subset (page) of fruits failed.</p>";
            }
          else
            {
            echo "<ul>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
                echo "<li>" . $row["id"] . "," . $row["name"] . ", " . $row["origin"] . ", " . $row["stock"] . "</li>";
                }

            echo "</ul>";
            }
        }
      else
        {
        echo

        // By default, load first page of records here

        }
    }

?>
```

Hi, I'm trying to load the first page of records by default where I have put the comment. There are no problems with the code, and the initial output is good. I'm just not sure how to show by default. Can anyone help please?

EDIT: Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of if statement, you should just be able to change

```
$currentPageNum = $_GET['page'];
$offset = ($currentPageNum - 1) * $totalItemsRequired;
```

to

```
$currentPageNum = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
$offset = $currentPageNum > 0 ? (($currentPageNum - 1) * $totalItemsRequired) : 0;
```

Full code:

```
<?php
$totalItemsRequired = 8;
$query = "SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY origin ASC ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ($result == false)
    {
    echo "<p>Selecting all fruits failed.</p>";
    }
  else
    {
    $totalRecords = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $totalPages = ceil($totalRecords / $totalItemsRequired);
    echo "<p>Page: ";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++)
        {
        echo "<a href='?page=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a> ";
        }

    echo "</p>";
        $currentPageNum = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
        $offset = $currentPageNum > 0 ? (($currentPageNum - 1) * $totalItemsRequired) : 0;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM fruits " . "LIMIT " . $offset . ", " . $totalItemsRequired;
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if ($result == false)
            {
            echo "<p>Selecting subset (page) of fruits failed.</p>";
            }
          else
            {
            echo "<ul>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
                echo "<li>" . $row["id"] . "," . $row["name"] . ", " . $row["origin"] . ", " . $row["stock"] . "</li>";
                }

            echo "</ul>";
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Could you implement this into the whole code as I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @bob123 If you don't see changes for your code, then it's probably not your code, because i have figure it out in under 10 secs to which part does it apply... and i am not author of your code ...

Comment: @KuKeC I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @bob123 This two lines of code are very easy to find and replace in your code. Stah don't need to implement this into whole code because it's too obvious what you need to change... If you still don't get it then i even more sure that this is someone's else code and not yours...

Comment: @KuKeC Well I have made the changes and there is no change in the behaviour of the output

Comment: @bob123 I updated the answer with the full code, please try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `LIMIT` clause in your MySQL statement?

```
SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY origin ASC LIMIT 8 //First 8 rows of the table
SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY origin ASC LIMIT 8,8 //Second 8 rows   
SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY origin ASC LIMIT 16,8 //Third 8 rows
```

**In General:**

`LIMIT offset,row_count` will return `row_count` rows starting from `offset+1` row.